# Inheriting Generics Interface in Java

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have interface with generics:

```
public interface Cache<CachePrimaryKey extends Object, RowModel extends CacheRowModel>
```

I need to create child interface that extends Cache but adds new methods **while keeping generics**. What would be the correct syntax to retain generics part?

I have implementation like.

```
public class InfoCache implements Cache<Long, DataRowModel>
```

I tried

```
public interface EnrichedCache<CachePrimaryKey extends Object, 
       RowModel extends CacheRowModel> extends  Cache
```

but when I change interface for InfoCache-class from Cache to EnrichedCache, I am getting "not overriding methods from its superclass". If I use "implement methods" in IntelliJ, instead of methods for Long+DataRowModel it offers methods for Object and CacheRowModel (which is not what I want).

What would be the correct way to inherit interface and retain all generics?

Comment: `public interface EnrichedCache<CachePrimaryKey extends Object, RowModel extends CacheRowModel> extends  Cache<CachePrimaryKey , RowModel>`.

Comment: Note that commonly adopted style guidelines require generic names to be **single capital letters**, or maybe several **capital letters**. Your naming conventions are the same as for classes, which is very confusing. For example what does `public interface Cache<String>` do, do you think?

Comment: Furthermore `Cache<CachePrimaryKey extends Object ...` is just plain wrong. Give me a type that doesn't `extends Object` (besides `Object` itself).

Comment: Thanks for the aswers, it worked. You can make an actual answer out of that so I can accept it. Regarding your last comment - that key is something I use for hashMaps, as a key. It can be Long or String. What else I can use besides Object?

Comment: `public interface Cache<K, R extends CacheRowModel>` would be the correct way to write what you want.

Comment: Thanks for input :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first, we use **capital letters** to represent generics, this is to avoid the following nonsense:

```
public interface Cache<String> {
    String getKey();
}
```

What do *you* thing the above `interface` does?

---

So, rewriting your `interface` as:

```
public interface Cache<K, R extends CacheRowModel>
```

<sub>note that `extends Object` is a nonsense, I have removed it</sub>

Then to create a generic `interface` that `extends Cache` and keeps the same generics we would do:

```
public interface EnrichedCache<K, R extends CacheRowModel> extends Cache<K,R>
```

i.e. we have a generic `interface` that has parameters `K` (can be anything) and `R` (must be a subclass of `CacheRowModel`) that `extends Cache` with the same parameters.

---

You can tighten the generics you pass on too:

```
public interface NumericCache<K extends Number, R extends CacheRowModel> extends Cache<K,R>
```

Here we require the key for `NumericCache` to `extends Number`.

You can also set one generic parameter to a concrete type and pass on the second:

```
public interface StringCache<R extends CacheRowModel> extends Cache<String, R>
```

Here we explicitly set the key of the inherited cache to `String` but allow the user to specify `CacheRowModel` to use.

Answer (score 0):

Your second interface extend the raw Cache.

Try this code:
`public interface EnrichedCache<CachePrimaryKey extends Object, 
       RowModel extends CacheRowModel> extends  Cache<CachePrimaryKey, RowModel>`